# Integrating Socket Io server with Android App

Tags: android, socket.io, real-time

Is it possible to integrate a Socket.IO server with an Android app to achieve some functions like real time chat or real time maps ? , I haven't found any solid resource or topic about this issue.

Comment: I've read quite a lot of android related question on just connecting clients, if you do get a basic example wrote that you don't mind sharing I would love to push a example topic to the socket.io documentation here on StackOverflow let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started you'll want to get a node server running and connected to your application, this guide is a good starting point for that https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

After which you'll want to install socket.io onto the node server which you can follow from the socket.io website here https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ This is an example guide for setting up a chat if you use the server section of this to setup stuff on the node server it will help understand how the information is passed between each component here.

```
SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://127.0.0.1:3001");
socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
    @Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
        if ("echo back".equals(event) && args.length > 0) {
            Log.d("SocketIO", "" + args[0]);
            // -> "hello"
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {}
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {}
    @Override
    public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {}
    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {}
    @Override
    public void onConnect() {}
});
socket.emit("echo", "hello");
```

This is an example of how your android application will connect to the node server at which point you can handle the sending and retrievin. of data via events.

Full example and more notes can be found here http://nkzawa.tumblr.com/post/46850605422/connecting-to-a-socketio-server-from-android